# Find a set where removing its isolated points creates more isolated points, then removing those isolated points creates more isolated points and so on

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For a set $E_1 \subset \mathbb R$, denote the set of all its isolated points by $E_1^*$.
Let $E_2 = E_1\setminus E_1^*$. Similarly, $E_3 = E_2\setminus E_2^*$, and so on. Give an example of such a set $E_1$ that meets the two conditions for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ :

1. None of the sets $E_n$ are empty
2. None of the sets $E_n^*$ are empty

Comment: Is it possible that $E_2^\star$ will be non-empty?

Comment: First find an example where removing the isolated points creates new isolated points. Looking at all real numbers of the form n+1/k where n is an integer and k is a positive integer is such an example. Now see if you can iterate.

Comment: @yanko by what the question is asking, doesn't it have to be? I honestly cannot think of a single set that fits this description.  I don't understand how removing isolated points can isolate nonisolated points in a set since they weren't touching in the first place

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip How are those isolated?  Is it because we're only looking at rationals and the irrationals are not part of our set so these points n+1/k are isolated?

Comment: Going on what @GrumpyParsnip Let $S_{\delta}=\{\frac{1}{k}+\delta:k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\delta\}$. Consider $S_0$ - It seems as though every point other than 0  is isolated. When we remove the isolated points from this set, we are left with the set $\{0\}$, which is clearly an isolated point. Now consider the set $\left(\bigcup_{\delta\in\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}S_{\delta}\right)\cup\{S_{0}\}$. This gives you a nonempty $E_i$ and $E_i{}^{*}$ for $i=1,2,3$  Maybe you could continue nesting these?

Comment: I guess it's worth pointing out that $E_2$ is called the derived set of $E_1$, and the theory behind this is due to Cantor--Bendixson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get sets $E_{n},E_{n}^{*}$ for $1\leq n\leq k.$ Let $X_{1}=\{0\}\cup\{1/n\}_{n\geq 2}.$ Now let $X_{2}=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\geq2}\{1/n\}\cup\{1/n+(1/(n-1)-1/n)/j\}_{j\geq 2},$ and proceed in this way for $k$ steps, i.e., between any two consecutive points that were added in $X_{n-1},$ $x<y,$ add the sequence of points $\{x+(y-x)/j\}_{j\geq 2}.$ Let $E_{1}=X_{k-1}.$ Then at the first step, the isolated points are just those that were added in the last step, since every point $x$ that was added in $X_{n},n<k-1$ has a sequence of points in $E_{1}$ tending to $x$ (added at step $n+1$). So $E_{2}=X_{k-2},$ and this continues until $E_{k-1}=X_{1}.$ We may repeat one more time to get $E_{k}=\{0\},$ but repeating further clearly yields the empty set.

Unfortunately, this isn't the example you want, since it may only be repeated finitely many times. $X_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}X_{n}$ doesn't have isolated points, since given any candidate $x\in X_{\infty},$ $x$ must belong to $X_{n}$ for some $n\geq 1,$ but that means that there is a sequence of points in $X_{n+1}$ with limit $x$, and this sequence also clearly belongs to $X_{\infty}.$

However, using the idea of martin.koeberl in the comment below, we may consider instead the sets $X_{n}^{*}=2n+X_{n},$ and let $E_{1}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}X_{n}^{*}.$ Now we have shown that $X_{k-1}^{*}$ will still be nonempty after $k$ steps in this procedure, for all $k\geq 1,$ which shows that $E_{k},E_{k}^{*}$ will be nonempty for all $k\geq 1.$ This gives the desired example.

The following picture describes the method for generating the $X_{n}.$ The green points in the first line are the points in $X_{1}=\{0\}\cup\{1/n\}_{n\geq 2}.$ On the next line, the points that were in $X_{1}$ are in red, and the added points are in green; the whole set of red and green points makes up $X_{2}=X_{1}\cup\bigcup_{n\geq 2}\{1/n+(1/n(n-1))/k\}_{k\geq 2}$ (note that $1/(n-1)-1/n=1/(n(n-1))$). This is repeated to generate $$X_{3}=X_{2}\cup\bigcup_{n\geq 2,k\geq 2}\{1/n+(1/n(n-1))/k+(1/n(n-1)k(k-1))/j\}_{j\geq 2},$$ and the process continues in this way.

[image: DescriptionForXnSets]

Comment: What if you just shift the sets. Let $X_n^{\#}=2n+X_n$ and then $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}X_n$. Then, after $n$ many derivatives, the pieces above $2n$ will still be non-empty, so you have infinite rank.

Comment: @martin.koeberl I think that does it! Do you mind if I add this to the answer?

Comment: Not at all, go ahead.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Thank you!  I still don't really understand what the $X_n$, you're starting with is. Could you please explain further or write out explicity the formula for $X_n$?

Comment: Do you see how I obtained $X_{2}$ from $X_{1}$? Between $1/2$ and $1$, I added the midpoint $(3/4)$, then the point a third of the way between them $(2/3)$, then the point a quarter of the way between them $(5/8),$ and so on to get a sequence converging to $1/2.$ I then repeat this between $1/3$ and $1/2,$ and similarly for each $1/n$ and $1/(n-1).$

Comment: @VinnyChase I've added a very poor rendition from MS Paint, for your viewing pleasure.